# Make contact firstname and lastname mandatory

Tags: validation, contact, fields, page-layout

This is a generic question.

**I was trying to make the first name and last name field of contact mandatory. Currently only the first name is mandatory**.

I tried doing this from the page layout. Now I saw that, **only the name field was visible there(not first name and last name)**. So I want to know is this usually the case? Or is is it possible to make the individual first name and last name mandatory from the page layout?

Comment: if this is the case then I suggest create validation rule for first name

Comment: welcome to the wonderland of salesforce.. :-)

Comment: I think you should seriously consider reading this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is a standard field, I don't think there's a lot you can do with this with respect to making them required fields.

A workaround would be to create a validation rule that checks whether or not both FirstName and LastName are filled.

The condition might be something like the following:

```
ISBLANK(FirstName) || ISBLANK(LastName)
```

This would return true if `FirstName` or `LastName` is blank.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest create a validation rule for first name.

Make first name required using validation rule
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create validation rule from

1. Setup | Customize | Contact | Validation Rules | New
2. Enter Rule Name and Description
3. Enter formula code **ISBLANK( FirstName )**
4. Enter the error message.
5. Select the Location where the error will be displayed.
6. Click Save.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but thought I'd suggest for you to try out (nor am I recommending it as a solution).

1. Change field level security of the first name and last name so they are hidden from all users.
2. Create 2 custom fields and add them to the page with the required status.
3. Create workflow rules to populate the standard fields with the custom field values.